# How to check for overflow from multiplication in a performant way?

Tags: java, math, overflow

Let's say I have:

```
int result = value1 * value2;
boolean isOverflow = ?
```

How do I check for overflow in a way that's performant? I found [this solution but it seems pretty expensive](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/Multiplytwolongintegerscheckingforoverflow.htm). I also noticed [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721316/dynamic-java-integer-long-overflow-checking-versus-performance) but there's no usable answer...

**Update:** There's no guarantee if the values are positive or negative.

Comment: If value1 and value2 are positive and the result is *smaller* than either value1 or value2, i'd say that would be a good indicator.

Comment: There's no guarantee on positive or negative

Comment: Giving the nature of the thing you want to do, I think the solution you've found is not that expensive after all, if you're worried about performance, maybe a better solution for you would be to validate ranges for your operands before doing the multiplication

Comment: `Math.sign(value1)*Math.sign(value2) != Math.sign(result)` should do the trick, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `checkedMultiply` provided in the `LongMath` class from the `com.google.common.math` package.
For info have look at the [java docs](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/math/LongMath.html#checkedMultiply%28long,%20long%29).

**OR**

The `Java 8` `multiplyExact` method from `Math` class. For java docs click [here](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#multiplyExact%28long,%20long%29).

**OR**

You could check overflow in the following manner -

```
long overflowCheck;
if(Math.sign(value1) == Math.sign(value2)) {
   overflowCheck = Long.MAX_VALUE 
} else {
  overflowCheck = Long.MIN_VALUE;
}

if (value1 != 0 && (value2 > 0 && value2 > overflowCheck / value1 ||
    value2 < 0 && value2 < overflowCheck / value1))
{
   isOverflow = true; 
}
```

Comment: I didn't realize the Guava libraries had this functionality. That works for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, the good news is that in the new JDK 8, in the Math class there will be methods to perform operations that throw overflow exceptions.

For instance the new [Math.multiplyExact](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#multiplyExact%28int,%20int%29) method throws an ArithmeticException when overflow occurs. Perhaps a good way to do it is by copying this exact implementation if you are working with a previous version of Java and that way, later, when you upgrade to the JDK 8, all you will have to do is to use the new JDK implementation for the method.

The current implementation in JDK 8 is as follows:

```
/**
  * Returns the product of the arguments,
  * throwing an exception if the result overflows an {@code int}.
  *
  * @param x the first value
  * @param y the second value
  * @return the result
  * @throws ArithmeticException if the result overflows an int
  * @since 1.8
  */
public static int multiplyExact(int x, int y) {
    long r = (long)x * (long)y;
    if ((int)r != r) {
       throw new ArithmeticException("long overflow");
    }
    return (int)r;
 }
```